# ThreadLocalRandom or new Random for each thread

Tags: java, multithreading, random, concurrency

Is there any difference when I create in each thread new `java.util.Random` object or use the `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(3);` ?

From what I've read, `ThreadLocalRandom` should be used instead of using the same instance of `java.util.Random` for all threads. But what if I create a new instance for each thread?

When should I use `java.util.Random` and when `ThreadLocalRandom` if I need to generate random numbers in multiple threads?

[image: screenshot of source code]

Comment: Well, using a locally created `Random` instance requires the JVM’s optimizer to find out that it’s purely local (to elide synchronization) whereas `ThreadLocalRandom` is purely local in the first place…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you create your own threads, like you do here, it makes no difference.

But if your code is called from different threads beyond your control, `ThreadLocalRandom` is the correct one to use.

There is one difference that does matter though: for obvious reasons you can't set a seed for `ThreadLocalRandom`. So if you want to have repeatable sequences, you need to create your own `Random` instances. (But then if you're running multiple threads, having your RNGs seeded to the same value doesn't always guarantee repeatable behaviour anyway.)

I would personally use `ThreadLocalRandom` in all cases where I don't need repeatable sequences.